# Correct flow when recipient view expire

Tags: docusignapi

If I get the recipient view expired (after 5 minutes), is the correct flow regenerate the recipient view with the same POST call on /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can always just generate another one at any time. The new view will also expire after 5 min. You should design your app to only generate this view when you redirect your users to the view and not earlier.